# ab is a number, finding (a+b)^n = ab

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Consider that we have the number 81, let's split it: 8 and 1. If we get this number's sum, it will be 9, right? Let's check if any power of 9 is 81. Yes, square of 9 is 81.

I want to find all this numbers until it reaches 10000. I have been coding this but there is something I'm always stuck. Here is my code;

```
var results = [];
for (var num = 0; num < 82; num++) {
    var splittedNumbersArray = num.toString(10).split("").map(Number);
    var sum = splittedNumbersArray.reduce(sumof, 0);
    var powersArray = [];
    for (var power = 0; power < 11; power++) {
        var powerNumber = Math.pow(sum, power);
        powersArray.push(powerNumber);
    }
    if (controlSolution(powersArray, num) === true) {
        results.push(num);
    }
}

function sumof(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function controlSolution(a, v) {
    for (var index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
        if (a[index] === v) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I debug the code via console, it says variable `num` is 82. But the `for` loop should stop after the 81, right? I check it too, it stops after the 81?! *(I understand this part.)*

Why it says 82 when I type `console.log(sayi)`? I think that's why my `kontrolet` function doesn't work.

When I check the `powersArray` if it is include `num` and I have seen, it is. But why `results` doesn't have the number 81?

How can i solve this problem? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Because the logic is... Increase the number by one and store the value, run the check to see if it is valid.... It does not revert the number back if it is not valid....

Comment: The loop stops when sayi=82, i.e. after it reaches 81.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong, but naming variables and functions in your native language instead of English makes it much harder to understand what the code does, and that may be problematic when you're asking for help from others who don't speak that language, e.g. on StackOverflow.

Comment: When I run it the `i` in your `kontrolet` function is undefined.

Comment: I second that.  Can you translate the function names to English for us?  It's very hard for my English-speaking-brain to follow.

Comment: The for loop runs, applies `i++` then checks the condition if it should continue.... in other words it will get to 81, see that the condition is still true, run again increment to 82, see the condition is false then move on

Comment: @patrick-barr I understand why it is 82 now. So, why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @KarlReid Sorry, my mistake :( I edited the text. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Frxstrem I changed the language to English, thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the for loop should stop after the 81, right? I check it too, it
>   stops after the 81?!

It does. But `sayi` is incremented *after every loop iteration*. So when `sayi` is `81`:

1. `81 < 82` is true, so the loop executes
2. the loop body runs
3. when it is finished, `sayi` is incremented to `82`.
4. the for loop condition is checked - `82 < 82` is false, so the loop terminates and we continue to the next line.

If you print `sayi` at this time, it will be `82`. But the loop last executed using a value of `81`, as you would expect.

This is normal behavior. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement which describes how the for loop works. Note that the **last** step is

> The update expression incrementExpression, if there is one, executes,
>   and control returns to step 2.

Step 2 is evaulation of the condition.

Comment: I understand why it shown 82, but why my code doesn't work? I checked `powersArray` and `num`, the array includes the number, but why it won't push?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is- when I run the code 81 is in `results`, is that what you want? See here : http://jsbin.com/debuxolubu/edit?js,console

Comment: yes, that's what i want. I tried code again and it worked. Thanks for everything.